# Error al analizar el paquete, cuando lo trato instalar desde código en android studio, manualmente si se deja instalar

Tags: java, android

El problema ocurre en android 6.0, en versiónes superiores si funciona bién

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    File file = new File(path) ;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
    }else{
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    }

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: en el archivo manifest tiene el permiso  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

Comment: En android 6.0 no funciona pero en los siguientes o anteriores sistemas operativos funciona sin problema? Recuerda que es importante revisar el LogCat para dar detalles acerca del problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al código que muestras puedes estar teniendo un error `FileUriExposedException`, para la API 24 debes usar `Uri.parse()` en lugar de `Uri.fromFile()`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      //i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
      i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  } else{
      i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  }
```

Comment: Gracias, el código si corrió bien lo que estaba poniendo mal era la ruta donde estaba la apk como que no tenía permiso de lectura no se, entonces guardé la app en la carpeta Download y ahí si funciona bién

Comment: Ok entonces era el directorio, trata de agregar en tus preguntas el mensaje de error del LogCat y con eso puedes saber super´rápido cual es el problema que afecta. de cualquier forma asegura usar Uri.parse() para versiones mayores a 6, saludos.!

Comment: gracias por el dato lo tomaré en cuenta, saludos 1